# Can't change property of this

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I was trying to create a custom save method so as not to store user passwords as plain text. But it seems whatever I do to change the value of this.values doesn't have any effect. This is my sequelize model:

```
module.exports= function (sequelize, DataTypes){
return sequelize.define("Users",{
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    is_admin: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
},{  instanceMethods: {
    user_save: function(){
        if(this.isNewRecord){
            var salt = 'blahblahblah';
            var key128Bits = CyrptoJS.PBKDF2(this.values.password, salt, { keySize: 128/32 });
            delete this.values.password;
            this.values.password = key128Bits.toString()
            console.log('new record ' + key128Bits.toString())
        }
        console.log(this.values)
        this.save();
        return
    }}
  }
);};
```

the first log statement confirms that the code inside the if isNewRecord is running, and generating a hash, the second log statement and the output indicate that the properties of this remain unchanged from their original values. Does anyone know why this is or how I can fix the problem?

I could do this immediately after a post request but I'd rather do it this way if possible.

Comment: check `this.values` near first log

Comment: @XMen Same as the one beneath it.

Comment: try setting `this.password` instead of `this.values.password`

Comment: http://www.sequelizejs.com/#instances-update-save

Comment: @XMen this.password fixed it, but I imagine the second option would also work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sequelizejs.com/#instances-update-save

set `this.password` instead of `this.values.password`

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `this.values` is actually only a getter which returns all the attributes with its respective values. It might be a good idea to add also a setter. But then there is the question if the setter should update the database or not. So basically `this.values` should only be used for stuff like `console.log`. Also it's used internally for `instance.toJSON()`.

And as XMen already answered correctly, you have to use `this.password` instead of `this.values.password` :)